# Connecting SQL Server from PHP 7.4 / Ubuntu 20

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am having trouble in Connecting to SQL Server remotely from PHP/Ubuntu 20.

Currently My PHP version is PHP7.4.I used this document to install the ODBC Driver

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-ubuntu
(I have replaced the php version to 7.4 wherever it was 8.0).

Restarted the server and checked PHP Info. Seems its installed check screenshot

[image]
[image]

Now I am trying to connect to `SQL Server`. The SQL Server Access was given in IP, Username and Password. I am able to connect to `database` from `HeidiSQL` tool.

When I connect through PHP Code:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=". $serverName .";Database=". $databaseName, $uid, $pwd);
```

or

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "database" => "<mydbname>",
    "uid" => "<dbusername>",
    "pwd" => "<dbpass>"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```

both given me error:

> SQLSTATE: 08001
> Code: 10054
> Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

Can anyone help in I don't know what I should follow. Is something I need to check on installation side, I mean on Ubuntu server or I should ask to SQL Server provider if they need to do something on their end.

Comment: Since it's a remote server, and possibly sitting behind a firewall, can you telnet to the server on tcp/1433?

Comment: make sure you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
Very easy to miss that little block in the guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too late. Anyway I am answering my own question for someone who face same issue again. I have resolved this by installing an OpenSSL on the server.

Follow these steps for installation

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username